# Generate a uniform distribution from n coin flips

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm making a computer game and I've reduced the problem into something simple: How can I show the player the number of heads he "tossed" given some number of coins = n? Naive expected value is worthless, since if coins = 3, we would always give 1 heads or 2 heads, depending how you round (Expected value = 3*0.5 = 1.5).

The solution is to instead simply sample the uniform distribution 3 times, then just say what we got. It could return 3 heads, 2, 1, 0. However, instead of doing 3 calculations, we can just do one sample on a normal distribution. Here is the one for 3 coins:

HHH
HHT
HTH
HTT
THH
THT
TTH
TTT

0 heads = 1
1 heads = 3
2 heads = 3
3 heads = 1

Average = 0*1 + 3*1 + 3*2 + 1*3   /   8   = 12/8 = 1.5
Variance = (0-1.5)^2 * 1/8 + (1-1.5)^2 * 3/8 + (2-1.5)^2 * 3/8 + (3-1.5)^2 * 1/8 = 0.75

StdDev = sqrt(0.75) = 0.866666

We have our parameters. Now, just sample a standard normal distribution and return the number of heads as: average + sample*stdDev.

So how do I do this for arbitrary n? Is there a nice way to calculate mean and stdDev on the fly? And can we extend it to not just be coins (50% probability). Ideally, I want to figure out how to do this with arbitrary probability p of heads, (1-p) of tails. In this case, HHH wouldn't be 1/8, it would be p^3, and so on.

So to summarize, we are looking for:
Given n coins with probability of heads = p, tails = 1-p, "flip" the n coins and return the number that are heads. With a normal distribution, flipping just means getting a standard normal value and converting it to our mean and stdDev. Or, it could be any other way to efficiently solve the problem. The whole point is to give a fair, believable number of heads with as little computation as possible. When n gets big, like 100,000, it becomes too expensive to run n individual trials and sum the number of heads.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

and also of import, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation

Comment: Using a normal distribution is a great idea. Sample a value from $\mathcal N(np, np(1-p))$ and consider using the "continuity correction" as discussed in the Wiki link above.

Comment: My mind was just blown... n*p*(1-p) = 0.75 for n = 3, p = 0.5 just like I calculated above (Well, for the variance). I will have to read further and derive how that worked out... could just be the nature of Bernoulli probability functions. This is perfect, I will just "manually" roll the dice for n < 5 or < 10, etc. Then, for n >= minimum, I will sample the normal distribution. Basically, I need to test performance and find what minimum such that manually rolling each uniform sample takes LONGER than just sampling a normal distribution. DaleM answered below, Ill accept it. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution.

$$\mu=np$$

$$\sigma=\sqrt {np(1-p)}$$

$$B(X\le x)\approx N(X\le x+0.5)$$

Comment: This is beautiful! I will simply find the smallest value of n where "manually" tossing each coin is less efficient than the above calculations. Then I will have a simple piecewise function... 1. If n <= minVal, manually roll. Else, sample normal. Thanks very much again!

Comment: I see you also included the continuity correction (The +0.5). Thanks!